# Kirby calculus on Mazur manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, kirby-calculus

I have questions about Akbulut and Kirby's paper [Mazur manifolds](http://www.selmanakbulut.com/papers/12.pdf).

I couldn't figure out the following equality passages:

[image: Figure 23]

[image: Figure 23]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rolfsen's book: Knots and Links especially section 9H is a good resource for working through examples like this. Granted this section does rely on previous sections especially the linking number section, but that can be useful background too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Here is a proof with pictures. Observe that blowing up and blowing own doesn't change the 3 manifold,i.e, the boundary. So all these above pictures  have same boundary. As a 3 manifolds all of these are isomorphic.